# What is "thirteen twenty-fourth" in a company's share?

Tags: meaning-in-context, numbers

English is not my mother tongue and when I was reading a book written in English, I've come across this sentence:

> I own thirteen twenty-fourth shares in Crptipa Mining Corporation

I didn't understand how many shares the speaker owns.

It's from "The Liar's Key" by Mark Lawrence.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Thanks for providing the source and writing your question in good formatting and with correct tags. These little things make it easier for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "share" is a fraction of ownership of a company.  The ownership of this company has been divided into 24 parts. So each share is 1/24 (one twenty-fourth) of the company.

This person owns 13 such shares.

This means that they own over half the company. They have a controlling stake, and can overrule any other shareholders at the company meetings.